# Which Google APIs to use?

Tags: google-api

I want to do the following things in my iOS app:

- Let a user create a new Google Spreadsheet, or choose from a list of
  existing Google Spreadsheets
- Let my app read data from a Google Spreadsheet
- Let my user edit a Google Spreadsheet, either by embedding the
  spreadsheet, or by switching over to Safari or a Google app.

There are a lot of Google APIs out there…which should I look at to accomplish the above three tasks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Drive API to create sheets: https://developers.google.com/drive/

You need the Sheets API to work with them (editing the file): https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en

You can find information on how to authenticate your Google requests (OAuth2) in the linked pages. The Drive API is built into the Google play services library but you'll need to get the Sheets API separately.

Comment: If I just want to read a spreadsheet, not write to it…I assume the Sheets API is still the best way to go? Thanks.

Comment: @GregMaletic yeah, you can just create a sheet and not modify it.